On button hover, textblock needs to display some text in c#
I have a button. On mouse hovering on the button, a textblock used in my project should display some value. Button is defined in the library and that library I am using in my project. In my project I have defined the textblock. So the button is created using code, in my project and on hovering it, the textblock should display some value. How this can be achieved. I heard using depenedency property it can be achieved. I am new to wpf and I am not sure how to do this. Could you help.
In the library I have added the following code, rest Iam not sure how to do. I am using MVVM.
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>


Bind TextBlock.Text to a string property in view model of the view, where it's added. You didn't show much, so it's yet a question how to optimally set its value depending on button hover. Do you have button instance somewhere? Use itsMouseEnter/MouseLeave events (can be done with attached behavior to comply with MVVM). Does the button belong to a view with view model? You can set the bool property there and monitor for it from TextBlock's view model. Maybe adding [mcve] where button and TextBock relation are demostrated would help.

button is with view and viemodel. since its mvvm iam struggling. i am not sure how to use dependency property. mostly I think using action delegate or func delgate this can be invoked. I am not sure about how this relationship btwn button and textblock can be achieved. Button click event is handled using delegate

Also, a relevant tag for the UI-technology (WPF, MAUI, Avalon, ...) is missing. See also ToolTip Overview.

Are you sure you don't just want to set the Button's ToolTip?

Requirement I got is to show the description in textblock

DependencyProperty are typically needed when creating custom controls (because they are already based on DependencyObject) to bind values. Do you have custom control? Show it. The TextBlock.Text is dependency property, you don't need another dependency property in view model.

using mouseenter how to write in this scenario. button is in library and textblock in project

A ToolTip is a "ContentControl"; which means it can contain "anything"; including "TextBlocks". Hooking the "Opened" event means you can customize this content "on the fly"; since "sender" in this case, is the ToolTip.

Okay, I easily managed to do it using DataTrigger. However, I have no idea where your text block's text comes from, so I assumed it is static. I've demonstrated triggering the setters of the two text block's properties, Text and Visibility even if it seems to be redundant, only to give you an idea and some choice.
The key to referencing a different element in a DataTrigger binding is using ElementName, please pay attention for the name trigger in Binding = "{Binding ElementName = trigger, Path = IsMouseOver}".
Just for comparison, I also added a regular Style.Triggers Trigger to trigger the background color of the same element, the Button instance.
Here is a complete working XAML sample with no code behind involved:
<Window x:Class="SampleWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    Title="Triggering Another Element's Properties" Height="450" Width="800"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Window.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="Padding">4</Thickness>
    <Style x:Key="Border" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4 0 4 0"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </Trigger>
                    <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Padding="{StaticResource Padding}">
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding = "{Binding ElementName = trigger, Path = IsMouseOver}" Value = "true">
                            <Setter Property = "TextBlock.Text" Value = "Before clicking on this button, think twice"/>
                            <Setter Property = "TextBlock.Visibility" Value = "Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding = "{Binding ElementName = trigger, Path = IsMouseOver}" Value = "false">
                            <Setter Property = "TextBlock.Text" Value = ""/>
                            <Setter Property = "TextBlock.Visibility" Value = "Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Navy" BorderThickness="3" Style="{StaticResource Border}" Margin="3">
        <TextBlock>Some useful content</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="2" Padding="{StaticResource Padding}">
        <StatusBarItem>
            <Button x:Name="trigger">Click it!</Button>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>

Of course, you can trigger more than one text value using a different combination of different Button properties. However, the set of those string values has to be static. Naturally, if you need to calculate different string values for TextBlock.Text dynamically, you will have to do everything in your code behind.
